# im in confusion about this logic, can someone explain me this min and max

Tags: javascript

var = randNum;

function getRandomNum(min, max){
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max- min + 1)+ min)

randNum = getRandomNum(1 , 6);

console.log(randNum);

Comment: The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527820/479156) uses the same logic and also explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's breakit down
We need to find random number in `range (min, max)`

`Math.random()` returns a random number between `0 and 1(excluded)` Ex (0.1, 0. 245, ... so on)
Since our range starts from min
Hence we need to add min to the random number `min + Math.random()`

But this will allow you random values only from `min` to `min + 1`

To make sure that we cover the entire range from min to max, we multiply the difference between those numbers `max - min`

This is good, but we only need `Integer` numbers, hence we round it to floor value using `Math.floor`
And to account for that exclude `1` from `Math.random()` we add it to the value

Hence it becomes `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max- min + 1)+ min)`